# Total sum fields from joined tables

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Query for Order tables:

```
SELECT O.ID, C.SecondName, E.SecondName, O.DateOf , O.ClientID, O.EmployeeID, O.Desc
FROM ((Client AS C INNER JOIN [ORDER] AS O ON C.ID = O.ClientID) 
    INNER JOIN Employee AS E ON E.ID = O.EmployeeID)
```

Query for Order Items tables:

```
SELECT  OrderItem.ID, 
        ProductID, 
        OrderID, 
        Quantity, 
        P.Title,
        P.CurrentPrice, 
        P.ID, 
        (P.CurrentPrice* OrderItem.Quantity) AS Total
FROM 
    OrderItem 
INNER JOIN 
    Product AS P 
ON 
    OrderItem.ProductID = P.ID
GROUP BY 
    OrderID,
    OrderItem.ID, 
    ProductID, 
    Quantity, 
    P.Title,
    P.CurrentPrice, 
    P.ID
```

and for total order price:

```
select OrderID, sum(Total)
from (
SELECT 
    OrderItem.ID
    , ProductID
    , OrderID
    , Quantity
    , P.Title
    ,P.CurrentPrice
    , P.ID
    , (P.CurrentPrice* OrderItem.Quantity) AS Total
FROM OrderItem 
INNER JOIN Product AS P ON OrderItem.ProductID = P.ID
) t 

group by OrderId
```

How i can joined tables for get total order price field for Order's table?

Comment: Instead of posting the queries that generated those data sets you are trying to use, modify your post to show samples of what the data looks like. Then, post a sample of what you want the output to look like. Finally, post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Sandly, i not used sql for create tables, and used GUI for it. And i never work with sql sub queries before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The third query, what you call "total order price", has an unnecessary subquery and fields. Here's the equivalent:

```
SELECT 
    OrderID, 
    Sum(P.CurrentPrice* OrderItem.Quantity) AS OrderTotal
FROM OrderItem INNER JOIN Product AS P ON OrderItem.ProductID = P.ID
GROUP BY OrderId
```

2) I interpret your request for "order price field for Order's table" to mean that you want to get order details along with the order price.(?)  You have already demonstrated the proper multi-table joins in your first query.  Just follow that same pattern to join in the [Order] table... and optionally the client and/or employee tables.

Only the order table:

```
SELECT  
    O.ID, O.DateOf , O.ClientID, O.EmployeeID, O.Desc,
    Sum(P.CurrentPrice* OrderItem.Quantity) AS [OrderTotal]
FROM
    ([Order] As O INNER JOIN OrderItem ON O.ID = OrderItem.OrderID)
    INNER JOIN Product AS P ON OrderItem.ProductID = P.ID
GROUP BY 
    O.ID, O.DateOf , O.ClientID, O.EmployeeID, O.Desc
```

The *key idea* is that any selected field that is not in your `sum()` or other aggregate function must be in the Group By clause.

```
SELECT  
    O.ID, C.SecondName, E.SecondName, 
    O.DateOf , O.ClientID, O.EmployeeID, O.Desc,
    Sum(P.CurrentPrice* OrderItem.Quantity) AS [OrderTotal]
FROM ((
    (Client AS C INNER JOIN [ORDER] AS O ON C.ID = O.ClientID)
    INNER JOIN Employee AS E ON E.ID = O.EmployeeID)
    INNER JOIN OrderItem ON O.ID = OrderItem.OrderID)
    INNER JOIN Product AS P ON OrderItem.ProductID = P.ID
GROUP BY 
    O.ID, C.SecondName, E.SecondName, O.DateOf,
    O.ClientID, O.EmployeeID, O.Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need next each row thw sum_total you could join this way

(otherwise you should work on presentation layer merging the two query using a loop over orderID)

```
select 
    t1.ID
  , t1.ProductID
  , t1.OrderID
  , t1.uantity
  , t1.Title
  , t1.CurrentPrice
  , t1.PID
  , t1.Total
  , T2.sum_total
FROM( 
  SELECT  OrderItem.ID, 
          ProductID, 
          OrderID, 
          Quantity, 
          P.Title,
          P.CurrentPrice, 
          P.ID  AS PID, 
          (P.CurrentPrice* OrderItem.Quantity) AS Total
  FROM 
      OrderItem 
  INNER JOIN 
      Product AS P 
  ON 
      OrderItem.ProductID = P.ID
  GROUP BY 
      OrderID,
      OrderItem.ID, 
      ProductID, 
      Quantity, 
      P.Title,
      P.CurrentPrice, 
      P.ID
  ) t1 
INNER JOIN(
    select OrderID, sum(Total) sum_total
    from (
    SELECT 
        OrderItem.ID
        , ProductID
        , OrderID
        , Quantity
        , P.Title
        ,P.CurrentPrice
        , P.ID
        , (P.CurrentPrice* OrderItem.Quantity) AS Total
    FROM OrderItem 
    INNER JOIN Product AS P ON OrderItem.ProductID = P.ID
    ) t 
    group by OrderId
) t2 on t1.OrderID = t2.OrderID
```

Comment: MS Access says that The specified field t1.ID could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov   . asnwer updated ... there was a id form P table and and id from t tabl ...now the P.ID use the PID alias